# Getting the attribute text from the custom attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have the custom attribute called *upgrade-test="secondary-pull mktg-data-content* in the following code snippet:

```
<section class="dvd-pull tech-pull-- secondary-pull--anonymous tech-pull--digital secondary-pull--dvd-ping tech-pull--minimise" upgrade-test="secondary-pull mktg-data-content" data-js="primary-pull" style="--primary-direct-d_user-bottom-pos:-290px;">
```

I am able to identify my element successfully by doing the following:

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@upgrade-test, 'mktg-data-content')]")
```

This `mktg-data-content` gets changed every time a user goes to a different page for example it could be `sales-data-content` for the sales page etc.

What I am after is to find a way to retrieve this dynamic text of this custom attribute and pass it to my variable. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the attribute value using `element.get_attribute("upgrade-test")` and then need to do string manipulation.

```
elementval = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@upgrade-test, 'secondary-pull')]").get_attribute("upgrade-test")
print(elementval.split(" ")[-1])
```

Note:- splitted with space,which returns zero based list, index `-1` means the last value of the list,
since you have two elements in the list you can use this as well
`print(elementval.split(" ")[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a unique locator for that element.
Without seeing that page we can only guess, so I can guess `tech-pull--digital` and `secondary-pull--dvd-ping` class names are making a unique combination.
If so you can use the following code:

```py
attribute_val = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.tech-pull--digital.secondary-pull--dvd-ping").get_attribute("upgrade-test")
print(attribute_val.split(" ")[-1])
```

The first line here locates the element and retrieves the desired attribute value while the second line isolates the first part of the desired attribute value as explained by KunduK